# Laravel - How to display nice columns names

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and a MySQL database.
In a view I want to display dynamically all my models attributes. ( Key : Value. , for example Name : John )

But these models attributes are the table colums names, so they are not in a nice formatting ( lower case, with some underscore )

What is the best way in Laravel to display nice name instead of database table columns names ?

Comment: Well if you need to format strings, you could just do `str_replace('_', ' ', $str)` and `ucwords($str)`; this'd add some basic formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple function to prettify your field names.

```
function prettify_field($field)
{
    return title_case(snake_case(camel_case($field), ' '));
}
```

Sample output

```
name            Name
age             Age
created_at      Created At
totalAmount     Total Amount
birth_date      Birth Date
theirPetName    Their Pet Name
```